# Getting WPTouch and W3 Total Cache to Work Together

Tags: plugins, plugin-w3-total-cache

I cannot get [WPTouch](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/) to work with W3 Total Cache. WPTouch admits that there is a known issue with the two, and they send you to [a tutorial](http://nimopress.com/pressed/blog-building-how-to-configure-w3-total-cache-to-work-with-wptouch-for-wordpress/). The tutorial is out of date, however, and does not work for me. Does anyone have WPTouch working with W3 Total Cache? If so, can you give some directions/instructions?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? I have a feeling it has to do with the device groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wptouch-w3-total-cache-must-disable-browser-caching

You'll need to add that long list to Rejected User Agents under Page Cache, Minify and CDN.

If your concerned about the browser caching issues when switching between mobile vs. normal themes, you'll need to add some query string pattern in the reject URIs field on the page cache settings tab.